# How to store and query an array of coordinates in C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.5.0 to interact with MongoDB.

I have an array of longitude and latitude coordinates and I want to store them in the MongoDB.

What is the name of the class used to store an array of coordinates? So I can lately do the following query, check If a given coordinate is near any point in the array of coordinates, how to achieve this?

Here is a simple code that demonstrate the question.

```
        var coordinates = new List<(double latitude, double longitude)>();

        //Store coordinates array in the database

        (double latitude, double longitude) point = (-33.847927, 150.6517805);

        int maxDistance = 300;//Max Distance in meters

        //Check if any point in the coordinates array is 300 m near the given point
```

**Edit:-**

According to this question mentioned in @CodeFuller comment below:-

[MongoDB geospatial index on an array (multikey + geospatial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570317/mongodb-geospatial-index-on-an-array-multikey-geospatial)

MongoDB doesn't support geospatial index on arrays, so consider the following classes:

```
class SomeDocument {

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> Locations {get; set;} = new List<MyClass>();
}

class MyClass {

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; 

}
```

How to get all instances of SomeDocument that at least have one point near a given point? And sort them by the nearest one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB .NET Driver provides `MongoDB.Driver.GeoJsonObjectModel.GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates` class for 2D geographic coordinates.

Here is basic usage:

1. In model class define the property with `GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>` type:

   ```
   public class SomeDocument
   {
       public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

       public string Title { get; set; }

       public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have `2dsphere` (or `2d`, depends on your needs) index for `Location` field. You could create and index via mongo client:

   > db.testCollection.createIndex( { Location : "2dsphere" } );

   Or via MongoDB .NET Driver:

   ```
   var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("testDB");
   IMongoCollection<SomeDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<SomeDocument>("testCollection");
   collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<SomeDocument>().Geo2DSphere(x => x.Location));
   ```
3. Inserting data:

   ```
   collection.InsertOne(new SomeDocument
   {
       Title = "Place #1",
       Location = GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(145.89, -35.83)),
   });

   collection.InsertOne(new SomeDocument
   {
       Title = "Place #2",
       Location = GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(154.98, -53.38)),
   });
   ```

   Note that in MongoDB you [specify longtitude first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513112/cant-extract-geo-keys-longitude-latitude-is-out-of-bounds).
4. Finding the neighbors:

   ```
   var point = GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(145.889, -35.831));
   int maxDistance = 300;

   IAsyncCursor<SomeDocument> cursor = collection.FindSync(new FilterDefinitionBuilder<SomeDocument>().Near(x => x.Location, point, maxDistance: maxDistance));
   //  Check whether at least one is near the point
   var hasNeighbors = cursor.Any();
   ```

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49779378-MongoDB-Near)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that the location field is an array of locations or in another words a route or a line how to achieve the near query with that?

Comment: MongoDB does not support geospatial indexes on arrays. The index could be created for the property that is basically one point. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570317/mongodb-geospatial-index-on-an-array-multikey-geospatial) for details. If you want to use MongoDB for finding near points, your only option for this moment is to create separate MongoDB document for each route point and use `$near` operator as in answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Ok What if the location is a property of a array of a nested  document could I achieve the near query. see my edit for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

Updates to @CodeFuller's answer.

Point 2.

`CreateOne( new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder..)` is depreciated. Instead use `CreateOne( new CreateIndexModel()...`.

Here's how:

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
                new CreateIndexModel<TDocument>(
                    new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>().Geo2DSphere(x => x.Location)));
```

Later I created a Generic function to created indexes on startup like this:

```
public CreateIndexes CreateGeoSpatialIndex<TDocument>(Expression<Func<TDocument, object>> field, string collectionName)
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<TDocument>(collectionName);

        try
        {
            collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
                new CreateIndexModel<TDocument>(
                    new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>().Geo2DSphere(field)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("already exists"))
        {
            // Log info
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Point 4.

Also, Near() didn't work for me, instead, had to use NearSphere() while querying.

```
var filterDefinition = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<T>().NearSphere(x => x.Location, lng, lat, maxdistance)
```